# Hyperledger fabric metrics

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

Just wanted to confirm if the fabric metrics is working for anyone? I'm using 1.1.0 release.

```
metrics:
    # enable or disable metrics server
    enabled: true

    # when enable metrics server, must specific metrics reporter type
    # currently supported type: "statsd","prom"
    reporter: statsd

    # determines frequency of report metrics(unit: second)
    interval: 1s

    statsdReporter:

          # statsd server address to connect
          address: 172.18.19.29:8125

          # determines frequency of push metrics to statsd server(unit: second)
          flushInterval: 2s

          # max size bytes for each push metrics request
          # intranet recommend 1432 and internet recommend 512
          flushBytes: 1432

    promReporter:

          # prometheus http server listen address for pull metrics
          listenAddress: 0.0.0.0:8080
```

This is my `core.yaml` configuration, I tried with both Prometheus and  Statsd but can't see any metrics with either of the methods. I can see the code present in the peer to export the metrics.

Can anyone please help with the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It's working on my environment with an exporter newly added by myself.
You need not only to change configuration in core.yaml, but also to implement your own exporter by using metrics package.

**Making your exporter**

1. Initialize viper & load core.yaml to enable metrics feature on peer node.
2. Configure metrics package by using core.yaml through viper.
3. Setup your metrics label. (In sample code below, label hyperledger_fabric_peer_blocknum is created)
4. Call Start() function. The function is blocked until when finishing export. So we need to execute it as a go routine.
5. And also you need to update your exported metrics periodically on another go routine. (In sample code below, the number of blocks is used as a metric)
6. In main thread, start to listen a channel to wait until interrupting.

```html
package main

import (
 "encoding/json"
 "fmt"
 "os"
 "os/exec"
 "time"

 "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging"
 "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metrics"
 "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common"
)

var logger = flogging.MustGetLogger("fabexporter")

var block_num metrics.Gauge

func main() {

 err := common.InitConfig("core")
 if err != nil {
  logger.Error(err)
 }

 opts := metrics.NewOpts()
 if err := metrics.Init(opts); err != nil {
  logger.Error(err)
  return
 }

 s := metrics.RootScope.SubScope("peer")
 block_num = s.Gauge("blocknum")

 go startMonitor()
 go func() {
  metrics.RootScope.Start()
 }()

 server := make(chan int)
 <-server
}

type Retdata struct {
 Height            int    `json:"height"`
 CurrentBlockHash  string `json:"currentBlockHash"`
 PreviousBlockHash string `json:"previousBlockHash"`
}

func startMonitor() {
 var ret Retdata

 for {
  time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

  cmd := exec.Command("peer", "channel", "getinfo", "-c", "mychannel")
  cmd.Env = os.Environ()
  cmd.Env = append(cmd.Env, "CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=CRITICAL")
  out, err := cmd.Output()
  if err != nil {
   logger.Error(err)
   continue
  } else if len(out) == 0 {
   continue
  }

  jsond := ([]byte)(out[17:]) // To trim "Blockchain info: " 
  if err := json.Unmarshal(jsond, &ret); err != nil {
   logger.Error(err)
   break
  }

  logger.Info(fmt.Sprintf("num of block : %d\n", ret.Height))
  block_num.Update(float64(ret.Height))
 }
}
```

I also wrote an article about it.
I hope it would be your help.

https://medium.com/@nekiaiken/hyperledger-fabric-meets-prometheus-649c452ba26a

Comment: oh! that's nice, will try it out. Was clueless about the exporter option.